# Cannot apply a page CSS to DIV for each topic in stackoverflow.com?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I usually apply a global CSS style with background-Color been set as a more eyes friendly color for stackoverflow.com, but it seem this doesn't work any more recently. Why my style below cannot be applied to all elements in the page?

```
var style = document.createElement('style');

style.type = 'text/css';

style.innerHTML = "html, body {background-color: #80C090!important;}"

document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild( style );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A div with an ID of 'content' also has a background-color assigned, which is sitting in front of the body background-color. Try this:

```
style.innerHTML = "html, body, #content {background-color: #80C090!important;}"
```